# Cakephp build error - getSchemaCollection

Tags: xampp, cakephp-3.0

I am quite new to cake and ran through a tutorial and had everything working however i am developing for real now.

I have a database set-up and the cake intro page says i am connecting to it, however when i do a “cake bake” on a table i get the following errors.

2018-06-13 20:06:44 Error: [Error] Call to a member function getSchemaCollection() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php on line 547

I don’t usually like to ask for help but i have searched and search for info on getSchemaCollection and can’t find anything!

The stack trace was

The stack trace was

One moment while associations are detected.
Exception: Call to a member function getSchemaCollection() on null in [C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php, line 547]
2018-06-15 11:45:46 Error: [Error] Call to a member function getSchemaCollection() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php on line 547
Stack Trace:

## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\bake\src\Shell\Task\ModelTask.php(415): Cake\ORM\Table->getSchema()

## 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\bake\src\Shell\Task\ModelTask.php(231): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->findHasMany(Object(App\Model\Table\PurchaseTable), Array)

## 2 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\bake\src\Shell\Task\ModelTask.php(130): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->getAssociations(Object(App\Model\Table\PurchaseTable))

## 3 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\bake\src\Shell\Task\ModelTask.php(113): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->getTableContext(Object(App\Model\Table\PurchaseTable), ‘purchase’, ‘Purchase’)

## 4 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\bake\src\Shell\Task\ModelTask.php(100): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->bake(‘Purchase’)

## 5 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\bake\src\Shell\BakeShell.php(272): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->main(‘Purchase’)

## 6 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Collection\CollectionTrait.php(51): Bake\Shell\BakeShell->Bake\Shell{closure}(‘Purchase’, 0)

## 7 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\bake\src\Shell\BakeShell.php(273): Cake\Collection\Collection->each(Object(Closure))

## 8 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\Shell.php(518): Bake\Shell\BakeShell->all(‘purchase’)

## 9 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\CommandRunner.php(342): Cake\Console\Shell->runCommand(Array, true)

## 10 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\CommandRunner.php(164): Cake\Console\CommandRunner->runShell(Object(Bake\Shell\BakeShell), Array)

## 11 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarker\bin\cake.php(12): Cake\Console\CommandRunner->run(Array)

## 12 {main}

And the version is 3.6.4

Jon

Comment: And that's the only error that you receive? In any case, whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion)! Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`).

Comment: i have edited to include the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Did your table name is **purchase** and not **purchases** ?